# Create Service in Kernel Which is Monitoring Multiple Packages on Android

Tags: android, linux-kernel, android-source

I want to write one **script(.sh file)** in the kernel which is continuously checking my System app.
if my system app is crashed or for any other reason it stopped. my script(.sh file) will start the application.

Anyone have this script example or any other method to do this?
in which location I have to add this script in the Android part?

Thanks.
Let me know if you give more details.

Answer (score 0):

In Android, you should handle this on the framework level.

Specifically ActivityManagerService is the system service which deals with this. You should debug and find the specific logic that is triggered when app crashes, so that you can there trigger a re-open.

Having searched a bit on the AOSP code, this seems to be the relevant file:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/AppErrors.java